# install TIbco ems 8.1 on linux

Tags: linux, tibco-ems

I am completely newbie to Tibco ems. I am trying to install tibco ems 8.1 on linux(ubantu 14.04). i got a universalinstaller package but not able to install it. it has multiple exe files. Please let me know if it has package specific for linux installation.As per tibco installation guide we can install on linux through universalinstaller. Please let me know if any one has any idea

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As mentioned by GhislainCote, check if you have got the right installer or not for the required platform.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [HOW-TO Install EMS 8 on CentOS 6](http://www.integist.info/2014/07/11/tibco-ems-on-centos-vm/)
(CentOS is a compatible free alternative to RedHat 6).

**But to answer more directly :**

You seem to be trying to install on linux with the Windows package.
TIBCO provides versions for Linux (and other OSes) in separate files.

When downloading your files from TIBCO, you can take the occasion to read the README file for the product.

In it, you will find the list of supported distributions.

As of now (EMS 8.2, Nov 2014), supported OS are:

- Mac OS X 10.9.x
- HP HP-UX 11i
- IBM AIX 6.1, 7.1
- Microsoft Windows 7 SP1, 8, Vista SP2
- Microsoft Windows Server 2003, 2008 SP2, 2012, 2012 R2
- Novell SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.3
- Oracle Solaris 11
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5,6 & 7
- Sun Solaris 10

NOTE : The command for running the installer in Linux is usually : *TIBCOUniversalInstaller-lnx-x86.bin*

Comment: Where do you get TIBCOUniversalInstaller-lnx-x86.bin from?. I am dowloading TIB_ems-dev_8.5.1_linux_x86_64.zip but there is no universalInstaller -_-!

Comment: it used to be a linux executable inside the zip file... first you must unzip into a folder.

Comment: I think that it doesn't come in the new versions. I manage to find an old one and it was inside the zip.